# Filter a table based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table of users that I need to filter by their activity based on a radio button changed.

I did it with Knockout but it doesn't work, I don't get an error, but the table comes up empty, am I do something wrong?

Without the filtering, the page works perfectly (when the foreach is on `users` and not `filteredUsers`)

The radio buttons:

```
<div class="btn">
     <input id="active" checked class="filterOpt selectedRadio" name="filterOpt" type="radio" data-bind="checked: inactive, attr: { 'value': 'false' }" /> <label class="filterLbl selectedRadio" for="active">ACTIVE</label>
</div>
<div class="btn">
     <input id="inActive" class="filterOpt" name="filterOpt" type="radio"  data-bind="checked: inactive, attr: { 'value': 'true' }" /> <label class="filterLbl" for="inactive">INACTIVE</label>
</div>
<div class="btn">
     <input id="all" class="filterOpt" name="filterOpt" type="radio" data-bind="checked: inactive, attr: { 'value': 'all' }" /> <label class="filterLbl" for="all">ALL</label>
</div>
```

And the KO code:

```
self.users= ko.observableArray([]);
self.inactive = ko.observable();
self.filteredClients = ko.observableArray([]);

self.filteredUsers= ko.computed(function () {
    var val = self.inactive();
    return self.users().filter(function (item) {
        console.log(ko.toJSON(item));
        return item.inactive === val;
    });
});
```

Then my table:

```
    <!--ko foreach: filteredUsers-->
        <table class="table">
            <tr class="header">
                <td class="name n" data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td class="rep" data-bind="text: email"></td>
                <td class="status" data-bind="text: inactive"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Your radio buttons returns the selected value as a string.  If the User object has `inactive` as a boolean, then the `===` always is going to return false, because you are comparing a boolean with a string.  This is a Codepen of example:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRoQqB.    You could see than `User 2` has a `true` as a boolean, and is not show (`User 1` is show).  Hope this helps.

Comment: @JoseLuis Thank you, I actually solved it by parsing to json the `inactive` observable. Would you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radio buttons returns the selected value as a string. If the User object has `inactive` as a boolean, then the `===` always is going to return false, because you are comparing a boolean with a string.

This is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRoQqB) as an example. You could see than `User 2` has a true as a boolean, and is not show (`User 1` is show).

This is the `User` object:

```
 function User(name, inactive){
    var self = this;
    self.inactive = inactive;
    self.name = name;
    self.email = "aaa@a.com"
  }
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
 function ViewModel() {
    self.users= ko.observableArray([
      new User('User 1', 'true'),
      new User('User 2', true),
      new User('User 3', 'false'),    
    ]);
    self.inactive = ko.observable();
    self.filteredClients = ko.observableArray([
    ]);

    self.filteredUsers= ko.computed(function () {
      var val = self.inactive();

      return self.users().filter(function (item) {
        console.log(ko.toJSON(item));
        return (item.inactive === val) || (val === 'all');
      });
    });
  }
```

As you can see, I create three `User`:

```
      new User('User 1', 'true'),
      new User('User 2', true),
      new User('User 3', 'false'),
```

The second has `true` as boolean, the others have a string.  If you change the boolean with a text, both users are shown.

Please, write you answer too.

:-)

Answer (score 1):

After @JoseLuis's answer, I was able to get it to work with a few minor changes, I post it in case someone in the future will run into a similar issue.

As @JoseLuis mentioned the problem was with the comparison of `Boolean` and `String`, in order to solve that I parsed the `String` to `Boolean` then I got a comparison between two booleans.

And this is the entire function:

```
self.filteredUsers = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.inactive() == "true" || self.inactive() == "false") {
        var val = JSON.parse(self.inactive());
    }
    else var val = self.inactive();
    return self.users().filter(function (item) {
        return (item.inactive() === val) || (val === 'all');
    });
});
```